# What is the current preferred method for enumerating the globals in a namespace?

Tags: intersystems-cache

I used to look at the source for %G for this, but lately Intersystems has stopped distributing the .INT code.  I guess in theory I could use an eXecute statement in a loop to check $D on every legal global name but that's silly and unreasonably slow.

So what is currently the right way to do it?

Comment: DAiMor and Stephen Canzano's answers both work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use special global variable [^$GLOBAL](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20121/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_sglobal)

for example:

```
s global=""
f { 
s global=$o(^$G(global))
  q:global=""
  zw global
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could always use the class query in [%SYS.GlobalQuery.](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20121/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25SYS.GlobalQuery)

Comment: This is actually preferred method because traversing ^$GLOBAL is slow. Regarding source code, you may look at ^%SYS.GD