# Silent exporting of globals using %GOF in Caché

Tags: intersystems-cache

I would like to know if it's possible to use "^%GOF" without user interaction. I'm using Caché 2008. ^%GO isn't an option as it's to slow. I'm using input from a temporary file for automatically answer the questions, but it can fail (rarely happens).

I couldn't find the routine of this utility in %SYS. Where is it located?

Thanks,

Answer: Using "%SYS.GlobalQuery:NameSpaceList" to get list of globals (system globals excluding).

```
Set Rset = ##class(%ResultSet).%New("%SYS.GlobalQuery:NameSpaceList")
d Rset.Execute(namespace, "*", 0)
s globals=""

while (Rset.Next()){
 s globalName=Rset.Data("Name")_".gbl"
 if (globals=""){
  s globals = globalName
 }else{
  s globals = globals_","_globalName
}

d ##class(%Library.Global).Export(namespace, globals, "/tmp/export.gof", 7)
```

The only drawback is that if you have a namespace with concatination of globals exceeding the maximum allowed for a global entry, the program crashes. You should then split the globals list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you look at the %Library.Global() class with output format 7.

- classmethod Export(Nsp As %String = $zu(5), ByRef GlobalList As %String, FileName As %String, OutputFormat As %Integer = 5, RecordFormat As %String = "V", qspec As %String = "d", Translation As %String = "") as %Status

  Exports a list of globals GlobalList from a namespace Nsp to FileName using OutputFormat and RecordFormat.
  OutputFormat can take the values below:
  1 - DTM format
  3 - VAXDSM format
  4 - DSM11 format
  5 - ISM/Cache format
  6 - MSM format
  7 - Cache Block format (%GOF)

  RecordFormat can take the values below:
  V - Variable Length Records
  S - Stream Data

  You can find it in the class documentation here: http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20082/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls

  I've never used it, it looks like it would do the trick however.

Comment: I know this class, but we can't use a regex ("*"), you must give all globals as a list.

Comment: I will try to figure out a way to get the list of globals to backup.

Comment: @user74952 - To list the globals, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793241/what-is-the-current-preferred-method-for-enumerating-the-globals-in-a-namespace

Answer (score 2):

export your global to file

```
d $system.OBJ.Export("myGlobal.GBL","c:\global.xml")
```

import global from your file

```
d $system.OBJ.Load("c:\global.xml")
```

> Export items as an XML file
>
> The extension of the items determine what
> type they are, they can be one of:
>
> - CLS - classes
> - CSP - Cache Server Pages
> - CSR - Cache Rule files
> - MAC - Macro routines
> - INT - None macro routines
> - BAS - Basic routines
> - INC - Include files
> - GBL - Globals
> - PRJ - Studio Projects
> - OBJ - Object code
> - PKG - Package definition
>
> If you wish to export multiple classes then separate then with commas or
> pass the items("item")="" as an array or use wild cards.
> If filename is empty then it will export to the current device.

link to [docbook](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20082/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25SYSTEM.OBJ#Export)

edit: adding "-d" as qspec value will suppress the terminal output of the export. If you want to use this programmtically, it might get in the way.

Comment: How can I get a specific node of the globals only? for Example, all globals that look like : ^BACKTR("INDX","COMPANY",1,,)

Answer (score 1):

And just for completeness' sake:

```
SAMPLES>s IO="c:\temp\test.gof"

SAMPLES>s IOT="RMS"

SAMPLES>s IOPAR="WNS"

SAMPLES>s globals("Sample.PersonD")=""

SAMPLES>d entry^%GOF(.globals)

SAMPLES>
```

-> results in c:\temp\test.gof having the export. You can define up to 65435 globals in you array (named globals in this example)

But I would recommend you go with DAiMor's answer as this is the more 'modern' way.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid maximum string error, you should use subscripts instead of comma delimited string:

```
Set Rset = ##class(%ResultSet).%New("%SYS.GlobalQuery:NameSpaceList")
d Rset.Execute(namespace, "*", 0)

while (Rset.Next()) {
 s globals(Rset.Data("Name"))="" // No need for _".gbl" in recent Cache
}

d ##class(%Library.Global).Export(namespace, .globals, "/tmp/export.gof", 7) // Note dot before globals
```